# Struts2 Wysihtml5 editor

Tags: struts2, wysihtml5

I have integrated Wysihtml5 text editor in my page.I have define parser rules from here (https://github.com/eyecatchup/wysihtml5/blob/master/parser_rules/allow-all-html5.js). When I get data from database,code formatted,link,image,bold,color,pre tag (define from textEditor) it is not working for me.It display text like here:[image]

Only paragraph tag works.Can any one helps me?I am using struts2 and hibernate.
Here is description attribute in hibernate:

Blog.java

```
@Column(name="description",columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT",length = 65535)
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(final String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

create.jsp

```
   <div>
                <s:textarea  id="wysihtml5-editor" cssStyle="height:400px" name="blog.description"
                    key="blog.description" placeholder="Enter Description..."/>
            </div>

<script>

      var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5-editor", {
        toolbar:     "wysihtml5-editor-toolbar",
        stylesheets :  ["<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/editor.css"],
        cleanUp:    true,
        parserRules:    wysihtml5ParserRules,
        useLineBreaks:  false

      });

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: version 0.3 ? Why not using something like CKEditor, or TinyMCE ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios, Because it seems me to simply to use.Can you help me to solve this problem and thanks to much for your suggestion! :)

Comment: Sure, no docs, no support, no 1.0 version... how should it be easier to use ? :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios , this advice from you it tells too much to me !I will tell my friend supporter and if he will agree with this i will change my editor :)